# Structure of Metallic Hydrogen

Tags: crystal-structure, metal, hydrogen

I am simply curious what the theoretical arrangement of metallic hydrogen would be.

I found [this](http://fuelcellsworks.com/news/2012/04/03/hydrogen-that-mimics-graphene/) article which gives a picture, but I don't understand what the labels mean (e.g. is H5 an isotope, some kind of charge, or just denoting the layer?).

I would like to know:

1) If the image is the correct one.

2) What the labels mean if it is correct.

Comment: The figure seems OK. The H1 , H2,H3 ,H4,H5,H6 numbers are just a label of simple hydrogen atoms, how they match up to the graphene like rings "graphene-like layers of hydrogen in irregular six-atom rings"

Comment: There are two substances here: metallic hydrogen, which has yet to be produced in the lab, and graphene-like hydrogen, which is what you link to. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Just whether the arrangement depicted for metallic hydrogen is accurate to the actual theoretical arrangement. Sometimes people add pictures that are not accurate, but easier to grasp to make their point.

Answer (score 3):

As annav states, the labeling H1, H2 etc is labeling of hydrogen atoms within a graphene-like hexagonal ring structure. Another way of looking at it, is in the image below:

[image]

[Image source](http://phys.org/news/2014-12-simplest-element-hydrogen-graphene.html)

In an article published after the web article you link to, [Aromaticity, closed-shell effects, and metallization of hydrogen.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25369180) (Abstract only), the authors confirm that

> Recent theoretical and experimental studies reveal that compressed molecular hydrogen at 200-350 GPa transforms to layered structures consisting of distorted graphene sheets.

This structure, according to the article, forms a stable structure at those pressures.  As per the comments, this is form graphene-like hydrogen, the abstract goes further, discussing the process that would result in hydrogen metallization:

> Metallization occurs upon further compression by destroying the closed shell electronic structure, which is mainly determined by the 1s electrons via lowering of the bonding bands stemming from the unoccupied atomic 2s and 2p orbitals.

This metallization of hydrogen is, according to the article [High temperature superconductivity in sulfur and selenium hydrides at high pressure](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1501.06336.pdf) theorised to occur at pressures of 400 GPa or greater.